# Find files that have not been copied from one directory to another file tree

Tags: shell

Consider the situation in which I copy files from one disk (eg an SD card)
to a given directory, eg. `/home/pepa/dir1`
but, later, subdirectories were created in dir1, and many files were moved to those subdirectories.
After a while, I want to clean the SD, but I would like to make sure first that all files
from the SD actually exist on dir1 or in any of its subdirectories.
How can I check that all files in the SD actually exist on dir1 or any of its subdirectories?
(Either through a command-line in the terminal or an specific linux utility)

Comment: You can use `rsync` for this purpose, you can achieve what you want using proper `rsync` flags

Comment: and which would be the "appropriate flags"? Note (i) the copied files have been moved to new subdirectories (thus the directory structure is no longer the same between both drives) and (ii) and do not want to automatically copy the missing files, but just to be listed.

Comment: how many files? 100s? 10000s 1000000s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming number of files is not too big:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sd=$1
dir1=$2

mkmap()(
    if cd "$1"; then
        find -type f -exec sha256sum {} + |\
        sed 's/^\\//'
    fi
)

awk '
    NR==FNR { k=$1; sub(/^[^ ]* ./,""); a[k]=$0 ; next }
    { delete a[$1] }
    END { print "missing files:"; for(i in a) print a[i] }
' <(mkmap "$sd") <(mkmap "$dir1")
```

`mkmap`:

- use `sha256sum` to compute checksums of files in a tree
- use `sed` to remove the indicator added by `sha256sum` to flag odd filenames

Then create maps for each directory tree and feed to `awk`:

- create map of checksum to filename for SD list
- remove any entries from map where checksum appears in DIR1 list
- for remaining map entries, print associated filename

Error-checking left out for clarity.

---

For extremely large number of files, one could instead generate the two lists, then `sort`, and feed to `comm`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sd=$1
dir1=$2

mkmap()(
    if cd "$1"; then
        find -type f -exec sha256sum {} + |\
        sed 's/^\\//'
    fi
)

map2sums()(
    mkmap "$2" |\
    tee "$1-map" |\
    sed 's/ .*$//' |\
    sort -u > "$1-sums"
)

map2sums sd   "$sd"
map2sums dir1 "$dir1"

comm -23 sd-sums dir1-sums |\
sed 's/^/^/' |\
grep -f - sd-map |\
sed 's/^[^ ]* .//'

rm {sd,dir1}-{map,sums}
```

`map2sums`

- generate and save map
- strip filenames
- sort and save unique checksums

Create both checksum maps and lists.

`comm` pipeline:

- use `comm` to output checksums that only exist  in SD list
- pipe to `sed` to convert checksums to regex
- pipe to `grep` to look for the regex in the SD map
- use `sed` to strip the checksum from the map and print associated filename

Then cleanup temporary files.

---

If you want something faster,

**AND** you only care if any file exists under DIR1 with the same **name** as a file under SD (i.e. you don't care if they contain the same content)

**AND** basename of files under SD are unique

**AND** there are not too many files (i.e. storing the list of names in memory is practical)

then you can try this alternative version:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sd=$1
dir1=$2

mklist()( cd "$1" && find -type f -print0 )

gawk -F/ -v RS='\0' '
    NR==FNR { a[$NF]; next }
    { delete a[$NR] }
    END { for (i in a) print i }
' <(mklist "$sd") <(mklist "$dir1")
```

- generate lists of the full paths of all files under each root and feed to awk
- for each path from SD list, store basename in map
- for each path from DIR1 list, delete basename from map
- print remaining map entries

The script handles files with any legal name but the output will be ambiguous if names can contain newline characters.

Note that, unlike the first two versions, this version will not produce sensible output if files have been renamed. For example, given this sequence of operations:

```
cd /dir1

cp /sd/f1 .
cp /sd/f2 .
cp /ds/f3 .

mv f1 f4

rm f2
mv f3 f2
```

this version will report that `/sd/f1` and `/sd/f3` are missing (and believe that `/sd/f2` exists), which is probably not what was desired.

Comment: the filenames output may have been encoded by `sha256sum`. this code does not reverse that encoding

Comment: In order to test the 1st script, I have copied it to checkcopy.scr and run `source checkcopy.scr /media/alobo/6234-3831/DCIM/111_PANA '/media/alobo/SP PHD U3/FOTOS/2022_VERANO/Planolas_Neva'` . The 1st directory has 811 files (including one for sure not in the second directory). The second directory has 129 files. I abort after 3', no message printed to the console.

Comment: `source` in inappropriate. do `chmod +x checkcopy.scr` and then run as `./checkcopy.scr ...`

Comment: the script will take as long to run as it takes to read the content of all the file in both directories and checksum them, then a small amount of time to process the checksum. the more files, the longer it will take. reading sdcrds is slow. if dir1 contains many files that will also be slow

Comment: Technically. my script doesn't check that sd files exist in dr1, it checks if files with the same content do. If you only want to check that a file with the same basename exists in dir1 for each file in sd and not that they actually contain the same content, you can do so much more quickly

Comment: Thanks. I confirm the script works fine for comparing file contents (2 identical files with different names are not listed, but this is not an issue). I see the risk of comparing names only, but it would be handy having an additional, fast script comparing names.